# IOS expo push notifications in app killed state

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v6

To give more clarity on the issue, i am developing this for IOS using expo push notifications and react-navigation v6 along with expo sdk44 in my current project.

I am having an issue when the user interacts with the notification while the app is in a killed state (the notificatiosn arrives succesfully with all of the data), what im having trouble with is, i want to navigate the user to a specific screen. The problem is because my `navigationRef is null`. Here i need to mention i did not create a seperate `RootNavigator`. Like it is shown here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/ .

What would be the "proper" way of handling this? So far i've tried putting all of the relevant push notification listener code inside NavigatonContainer's onReady callback ( this worked).

I also tried making a seperate `useEffect` and changing the state of a `isReady` variable and setting its new value in `<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} onReady={() => {setNavigatorReady(true)}}>` to force a rerender and thus running the code inside `useEffect` again.  (this approach did not work)

Just to sum up my current problem. When the user interacts with a notification while the app is in a killed state i want them to be navigated to a specific screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too am using `react-navigation 6.x` and `expo`. To tackle this problem I pretty much followed this section on `expo`'s docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#addnotificationresponsereceivedlistenerlistener-event-notificationresponse--void-void.

It shows you how to implement `addNotificationResponseReceivedListener` which is called whenever a user interacts with a notification. It works in all situations, even when the app is `killed`, which is the specific situation you are interested in.[image]

The docs also show you how to integrate this listener with `react-navigation`. Link: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#handling-push-notifications-with-react-navigation

Comment: I used a slightly different approach to avoid deep linking, because im executing certain operations depending on if the user clicks on the message or not, but i will mark this as the answer.